# Combining 3 columns into one TextView in ListView

Tags: android, listview, cursor

I have SQLite Database with some columns, 3 of them is `day` `month` and `year`. I have 2 TextViews in the ListView - Title and Date.

I want to combine the 3 columns of the date (day, month and year) into the "Date" TextView.

Example:

My SQL Database -

title - `title`

day - `8`

month - `3`

year - `2013`

and in the ListView it will look like -

```
title
8/3/2013
```

My code:

```
    c = db.query(DbHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null, null);

    String[] from = {DbHelper.COLUMN_NAME_TITLE, DbHelper.COLUMN_NAME_DAY, DbHelper.COLUMN_NAME_MONTH, DbHelper.COLUMN_NAME_YEAR};
    int[] to = {R.id.text1, R.id.date};
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            R.layout.list_item_2,
            c, from, to);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I think that I need to change the 3 date columns before it put into the TextView but I dont know how to do this.

Thank you!

Comment: you need to override `getView` of your adapter and join those three columns as one string

Comment: use custom SimpleCursorAdapter. refer this http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/10/list-images-with-thumbnails.html

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] date = { DbHelper.COLUMN_NAME_TITLE, DbHelper.COLUMN_NAME_DAY+"/"+ DbHelper.COLUMN_NAME_MONTH+"/"+DbHelper.COLUMN_NAME_YEAR};
```

or

```
String temp = DbHelper.COLUMN_NAME_DAY+"/"+ DbHelper.COLUMN_NAME_MONTH+"/"+DbHelper.COLUMN_NAME_YEAR
String[] date = { DbHelper.COLUMN_NAME_TITLE, temp}
```

I think this is what you ask for